# Checking Multiple textbox if they're null or whitespace

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I have a form where I have lots of textboxes and all of them are required to be filled out. In C# how do I actually if check there are group of fields having a null or whitespace?

I am familiar with `string.isNullOrWhiteSpace(string here)` but I don't want to do multiple if statements of that, it would result in a bad code.

I am trying to avoid something like this

```
if(string.isNullOrWhiteSpace(string here)
   || string.isNullOrWhiteSpace(string here)
   || string.isNullOrWhiteSpace(string here))
{
   // do something
}
```

Are there fix for this type of bad code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can query the controls collection of the form (or relevant container) and filter for textboxes and further query to see if any are empty (none should really have null values). Example:

```
var emptyTextboxes = from tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                     where string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text)
                     select tb;

if (emptyTextboxes.Any())
{
    // one or more textboxes are empty
}
```

You can do effectively the same thing using the fluent syntax.

```
bool isIncomplete = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Any(tb => string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text));
if (isIncomplete)
{
    // do your work
}
```

For this code, you should be working with at least Visual Studio 2008 / C# 3 / .NET 3.5. Your project needs to have a reference to System.Core.dll (should have one by default) and you need a `using System.Linq;` directive in the class file.

---

Based upon your comments, consider another method if you are having trouble understanding or working with the linq version. You can certainly do this in an explicit loop (the Linq code will ultimately be a loop as well). Consider

```
bool isIncomplete = false; 
foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
{
     if (control is TextBox)
     {
          TextBox tb = control as TextBox;
          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
          {
               isIncomplete = true;
               break;
          }
     }
}

if (isIncomplete)
{

}
```

---

Finally, this code is written as if all of the textboxes are in a single container. That container might be the form, a panel, etc. You will need to point to the appropriate container (eg., instead of `this` (the form) it might be `this.SomePanel`). If you are working with controls that are in multiple and perhaps nested containers, you will need to do more work to find them programmatically (recursive searching, explicit concatenation, etc.) or you might just preload the references into an array or other collection. For example

```
var textboxes = new [] { textbox1, textbox2, textbox3, /* etc */ };
// write query against textboxes instead of this.Controls
```

---

You said you have multiple GroupBox controls. If each GroupBox is loaded onto the form and not nested in another control, this may get you started.

```
var emptyTextboxes = from groupBox in this.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>()
                     from tb in groupBox.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                     where string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text)
                     select tb;
```

Comment: What part are you having trouble understanding? This is using Linq, which has been part of the last 2 releases of C# and Visual Studio (2008 and 2010).

Comment: you can query components? I never knew that are there any online documentation for that? I am quite interested I want to see more of its documentation with regards to querying components

Comment: You can write Linq queries against anything that implements `IEnumerable<T>`. Technically, the controls collection behind  `Form.Controls` does not implement this. However, it *does* implement `IEnumerable`, and the `Cast<T>` and `OfType<T>` extension methods are available on this interface, and *those* methods yield `IEnumerable<>` sequences, which gets us to Linq! So ultimately, you just need to do some research on Linq and the interfaces involved. A full or even rudimentary explanation of it is not in scope for this question, however.

Comment: @user962206 you can query any collection of objects. That said both [101 Linq Samples for Visual C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa336746) and [Getting Started with LINQ in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx) should be more than enough to get you started.

Comment: But when I tried wrting the code, there were erros, invalid expression of where, and System.Windows.Form.TextBox is a type but used like in a variable

Comment: @user962206 what version of .NET are you using? Do you have a using for `System.Linq` in the class you are trying to write this code?

Comment: ahsteele is correct. You need to be using a recent version of C# (if you are at least on VS 2008, you are fine). You should have a project reference to System.Core.dll (should have one by default). And you should finally have a `using System.Linq;` directive in your class file. This code certainly compiles once everything has been verified.

Comment: @user962206, added non-Linq code to show simply verifying this in a loop. You should be able to read and understand that. Consider how that compares to the Linq version, and notice how it ultimately translates to and performs the same logical operations.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram it is finally working but, when I press the submit button, there are textboxes that are empty but still no message is showing, I've added Message.Show("Please Complete The Form") inside the block of if(emptyTextBoxes.Any())

Comment: @user962206, this particular method works when the controls are all in a single container. If these are all simply on the form and not inside another container (such as a panel), it will find them. If the controls are all in a panel or some other such container, update the code to look in *that* container. If they are simply in multiple containers, you will have to do more work!

Comment: That work might be writing a method to recursively search through containers, it might be concatenating the controls collection from multiple containers together, or it just might be creating your own collection to hold references to the controls. At any rate, this code certainly works in a small program, but you are the only one who knows how your form is laid out.

Comment: Are GroupBoxes considered to be part of a container? since my textBoxes are inside several groupboxes, so  I need to query in that groupbox? wit that being said, I'll do this? from tb in this.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>() ?

Comment: @user962206, see my final update. Hopefully you will be able to find your way.

Comment: Alright, I updated my comment, please check. though thank you for giving me a view on how Linq works

Comment: @user962206, if the GroupBoxes are not nested, that will actually get you started. I put a version in the answer.

Comment: I removed my TextBoxes from the Group Boxes Since I just realized this group boxes doesn't have really sense at all. and overall thank you so much!

Comment: @AnthonyPegram last question what does .Any() do?

Comment: @user962206, well, in the context of the code, what would you guess it would do? In the first snippet, it simply tells you if there are *any* items in the sequence. It will return true or false. It does not need to walk the entire sequence, making it (normally) cheaper than using Count(). In the second example, there is a predicate involved. But it is still the same outcome, it simply tells you if any elements pass the predicate.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: When I try this 
`var emptyTextboxes = from tb in myStackPanel.OfType<TextBox>()
                                 where string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text)
                                 select tb;
`
the compiler doesn't like it, says `StackPanel does not contain a definition for OfType`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @JW, try myStackPanel.Controls.OfType (if .Controls exists).

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: Thank you for responding. I tried that but compiler still doesn't like it. Says "StackPanel does not contain a definition for Controls...". FYI, I am using wpf.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what you consider "bad code." Depending on your requirements what text boxes are required to be filled out can vary. Further, even if all of the fields are required all of the time you still want to give friendly error messages letting people know which field they didn't fill out. There a variety of approaches to solving this issue depending on how you are rendering your form. Since you haven't specified any here's a very direct method for doing so.

```
var incompleteTextBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                              .Where(tb => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb.Text));

foreach (var textBox in inCompleteTextBoxes)
{
    // give user feedback about which text boxes they have yet to fill out
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution.
This will recursively travel the whole control Tree , and Check for null or empty text in all of the textboxes. 
caveat - 
If you have some fancy controls not inheriting from the standard Winforms textbox - check will not be performed

```
 bool check(Control root,List<Control> nonFilled)
 {
    bool result =true;
   if (root is TextBox &&  string.isNullOrEmpty(((TextBox)root).Text)   )
    {
    nonFilled.Add(root);
    return false;
   }
   foreach(Control c in root.Controls)
   {
    result|=check(c,nonFilled)
   }
   return result;
 }
```

Usage :

```
  List<Control> emptytextboxes=new List<Control>()
  bool isOK=check(form, emptytextboxes);
```